# Do live tiles continue to update when I'm not looking at the start screen?

Tags: windows-8, battery-life, start-screen, live-tiles

If I glance at my start screen, do I need to wait a few seconds for the tiles to show up-to-date information? Or do they continue to update when I'm not looking at the start screen?

Comment: If a tree falls in the forest and there's no one there to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, but no one hears it, my trusty sound recorder I left behind proves it DID!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Live tiles are "live." You can actually check for or disable live updating by right-clicking a tile, waiting for an options bar to slide in, and clicking "Turn live tile off" on an app-by-app basis.  The weather app, mail app, and calendar app are quick examples of the automatic updating of Live Tiles.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They will update without you looking. A good example of this is the Finance app where it will update the stock prices on its own.

Comment: Also I think that's why Live Tiles are called "Live" Tiles :)